# EntityFramework: Model Configuration with Irregular Names in Plural

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, annotations, linq-to-entities

I have a system written in ASP.NET MVC4, EntityFramework Code First and Razor. One of the models has the following statements:

```
public class Flour : IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FlourId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProcessId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Timestamp", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FlourAnalyzes", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public virtual ICollection<FlourAnalysis> FlourAnalyzes { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Process", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LastModified", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "CreatedOn", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

As mentioned, `Flour` has a collection of `FlourAnalysis`. The model is described below:

```
[Table(name: "FlourAnalyzes")]
public class FlourAnalysis : IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FlourAnalysisId { get; set; }
    public Guid FlourId { get; set; }
    public Guid? MeshId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Timestamp", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "StartTimestamp", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public DateTime? StartTimestamp { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HumidityPercentage", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public Double HumidityPercentage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "StarchPercentage", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public Double StarchPercentage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Comments", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public String Comments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Flour", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public virtual Flour Flour { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Mesh", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public virtual Mesh Mesh { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LastModified", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "CreatedOn", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public FlourAnalysis() {
        this.HumidityPercentage = 0;
        this.StarchPercentage = 0;
    }
```

After generating the migration, EF created a table with name `FlourAnalyzes` (I need to force the table name, or else EF will create the table in singular). After inserting into it some data, EF doesn't bring `FlourAnalysis` data calling `Flour` objects via context:

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult Details(System.Guid id)
{
    var flour = context.Flours
        .Include(f => f.FlourAnalyzes)
        .Single(x => x.FlourId == id);

    return View(flour);
}
```

**EDIT:**

After some suggestions, I changed the `.Single()` expression to `.Where()` and the generated SQL points to a column that should not even exist, `Flour_ProcessId`:

```
{SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ProcessId] AS [ProcessId], 
[Project1].[FlourId] AS [FlourId], 
[Project1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
[Project1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
[Project1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Project1].[Mesh_MeshId] AS [Mesh_MeshId], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[FlourAnalysisId] AS [FlourAnalysisId], 
[Project1].[FlourId1] AS [FlourId1], 
[Project1].[MeshId] AS [MeshId], 
[Project1].[Timestamp1] AS [Timestamp1], 
[Project1].[StartTimestamp] AS [StartTimestamp], 
[Project1].[HumidityPercentage] AS [HumidityPercentage], 
[Project1].[StarchPercentage] AS [StarchPercentage], 
[Project1].[Comments] AS [Comments], 
[Project1].[LastModified1] AS [LastModified1], 
[Project1].[CreatedOn1] AS [CreatedOn1], 
[Project1].[Flour_ProcessId] AS [Flour_ProcessId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProcessId] AS [ProcessId], 
    [Extent1].[FlourId] AS [FlourId], 
    [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
    [Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Extent1].[Mesh_MeshId] AS [Mesh_MeshId], 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[FlourAnalysisId] AS [FlourAnalysisId], 
    [Extent2].[FlourId] AS [FlourId1], 
    [Extent2].[MeshId] AS [MeshId], 
    [Extent2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp1], 
    [Extent2].[StartTimestamp] AS [StartTimestamp], 
    [Extent2].[HumidityPercentage] AS [HumidityPercentage], 
    [Extent2].[StarchPercentage] AS [StarchPercentage], 
    [Extent2].[Comments] AS [Comments], 
    [Extent2].[LastModified] AS [LastModified1], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn1], 
    [Extent2].[Flour_ProcessId] AS [Flour_ProcessId], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[FlourAnalysisId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[Flours] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[FlourAnalyzes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProcessId] = [Extent2].[Flour_ProcessId]
WHERE [Extent1].[FlourId] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[ProcessId] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you rephrase the problem? It's not clear what's going wrong. From what I can gather, you might be interested in removing a convention `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`?

Comment: When I call `Details` method, in context call to bring the `Flours`, the related `FlourAnalyzes` are not retrieved. It's not necessary to remove the pluralized naming convention.

Comment: are you sure you have related entities in the database for the given id?

Comment: Yes. Actually I'm using a workaround that populates `FlourAnalyzes` using `flour.FlourAnalyzes = context.FlourAnalysis.Where(x => x.FlourId == flour.FlourId).ToList()`. This statement works.

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL query generated by EF? Can you post it here? (If you're using SQL Server then use SQL Profiler or an EF-specific tool.)

Comment: EF-specific tool? Like what?

Comment: Answer improved as requested.

Comment: It seems to try to join Flour and Analyzes on ProcessId instead of FlourId. Somehow there is a foreign key wrongly defined, it seems, but indeed that ProcessID should, from what you post, not even be present in Analyzes. On the other hand, if the column is not there, and you try to join on it, yuo would get an error from SQL Server. So it seems that somehow it _does_ exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the error you're getting regarding `Process_ProcessId` you need to add an attribute:

```
[ForeignKey("ProcessId")]
public virtual Process Process { get; set; }
```

This is because the *convention* for generating foreign keys would use the wrong column name.

You probably also need something like this in your `FlourAnalysis` class:

```
[ForeignKey("FlourId")]
public virtual Flour Flour { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("MeshId")]
public virtual Mesh Mesh { get; set; }
```

Note that, in all cases, I've omitted the other attributes from your code just to highlight what I've added.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) is an old-ish article that explains how you use the attribute.

A **useful tip** for working with pre-existing databases to see whether you've defined your mappings correctly is to install the [EF Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ593170.aspx) and use the **View Entity Data Model DDL SQL** option to see what EF *thinks* your database looks like.  Where the generated SQL does not match your actual database, you know you need to modify your model annotations or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Entity Framework will assume that all of the names of your tables in your database are either pluralised, or in the case of code first, you would like them to be pluralised when created.

check this hope it will help

http://edspencer.me.uk/2012/03/13/entity-framework-plural-and-singular-table-names/

Comment: As I commented before, my main concern is about the data retrieved. The table name generation is not a problem. But I thank you for your answer.